# Detect & Limiting Direction of Scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, position, fixed, locked

A website I recently stumbled across -

http://www.nuabikes.com/

Nuabike.com can detected & limit the direction the amount their users can scroll along the y-axis which then locks the page/panel into a position before moving onto another section of the website. (See link above)

Would anyone have an idea on how this has been created or know of any plugin's that achieves this?

I came across the plugin called [jQuery Panel Snap](http://guidobouman.github.io/jquery-panelsnap/) however it doesn't limit the amount of the scrolling along the y-axis and results in the user being able to pass/miss different sections of my website.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.